# How do i bootstrap ec2 instance with an external script file in terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

Can anyone of you help me with the following code in terraform? I am trying to bootstrap an amazon linux ec2 instance using an external script file. The external script installs tomcat on the ec2 instance.
The following code is failing to deploy tomcat on ec2.

terrform code:

```
data "template_file" "ec2_user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.cwd}/user_data_tomcat.txt")}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "lab_ec1" {
  ami = "ami-009d6802948d06e52"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "lab_keypair_1"
  #key_name = "${aws_key_pair.lab_key_pair.name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.lab_subnet1.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
      "${aws_security_group.lab_bastion_sg.id}",
  ]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.template}"

  tags = {
    Name = "lab_ec1"
  }
}
```

external script file:user_data_tomcat.txt

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum -y install tomcat.noarch
sudo yum -y install tomcat-admin-webapps.noarch
sudo yum -y install tomcat-webapps.noarch
sudo yum -y install tomcat-lib.noarch
sudo service tomcat start
```

How do i bootstrap ec2 instance with an external script file in terraform?

Comment: "code below did not work.anything else missing?"
data "template_file" "ec2_user_data" {
  template = "${file("user_data_tomcat.txt")}"
}
resource "aws_instance" "lab_ec1" {
  ami = "ami-009d6802948d06e52"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "lab_keypair_1"
  #key_name = "${aws_key_pair.lab_key_pair.name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.lab_subnet1.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
      "${aws_security_group.lab_bastion_sg.id}",
  ]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.rendered}"

  tags = {
    Name = "lab_ec1"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following variable is incorrect:

```
user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.template}"
```

You should use `rendered` attribute instead of `template` as described in the following link: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html#rendered

Comment: tpl naming is not a standard. I would remove that statement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and sorry it was in fact a confusion on my side. Indeed I thought it was a Terraform standard but after some research I discovered that it wasn't, so I removed my statement. However I still believe that `.tpl` as `template` is more explicit/relevant than `.txt` ^^

Comment: user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.rendered}" is not working either

Answer (score 0):

You must verify that logging into the system, becoming root and running this works to start Tomcat:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum -y install tomcat.noarch
sudo yum -y install tomcat-admin-webapps.noarch
sudo yum -y install tomcat-webapps.noarch
sudo yum -y install tomcat-lib.noarch
sudo service tomcat start
```

If not, it can't work as **user_data** either. Make sure to verify it interactively first before attempting it as **user_data**.

Make sure the path to the **file** used in the **template** of the **template_file.ec2_user_data** resource is correct. I have revised the snippet from your question to use **path.module** (relative to the TF file) rather than **path.cwd** (relative to directory where the terraform command is run)

```
data "template_file" "ec2_user_data" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/user_data_tomcat.txt")}"
}
```

Make sure that the file **user_data_tomcat.txt** is in the same directory as the TF file where you declare **template_file.ec2_user_data**.

You have used **template** in the user_data like this:

```
user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.template}"
```

**template** will get the internally encoded version of the original template file without substituting variables. You have no variables in the template, so it's likely the text encoding causing it to fail. Sending that as the user_data in my experience never works since the text encoding used interacts badly with cloud-init or bash. You can check /var/log/cloud-init-output.log for evidence of the failure.

Instead, you should use **rendered** in user_data like this:

```
user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.template}"
```

Here is the full, corrected resource block:

```
resource "aws_instance" "lab_ec1" {
  ami = "ami-009d6802948d06e52"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "lab_keypair_1"
  #key_name = "${aws_key_pair.lab_key_pair.name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.lab_subnet1.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
      "${aws_security_group.lab_bastion_sg.id}",
  ]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.rendered}"

  tags = {
    Name = "lab_ec1"
  }
}
```

Comment: "below code did not work.anything else missing?"
data "template_file" "ec2_user_data" {
  template = "${file("user_data_tomcat.txt")}"
}
resource "aws_instance" "lab_ec1" {
  ami = "ami-009d6802948d06e52"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "lab_keypair_1"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.lab_subnet1.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
      "${aws_security_group.lab_bastion_sg.id}",
  ]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.rendered}"
  tags = {
    Name = "lab_ec1"
  }
}

Comment: I did not suggest that code and it has a different path for the **file** used in the **template** of the **template_file** resource.  What error message did you get?

Comment: @devopseng I've revised my answer to provide additional troubleshooting guidance for the template_file path. Hopefully that is what was missing.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the remote-exec provisioner, but in that case I recommend you use userdata https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data

```
user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.rendered}"
```

Comment: user_data = "${data.template_file.ec2_user_data.rendered}" is not working.